# Error when trying to add a scaffolded item in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have been trying to add a scaffold item in ASP.NET Core, razor pages using Entity Frameword (CRUD). My current target framework is `netcoreapp3.1`.

I have the following package versions:

- `Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.9"`
- `Include="Microsoft.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.9"`
- `Include="Microsoft.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core" Version="3.1.4"`

This is the instructions I am following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-student-pages.

However, when I try adding a scaffold item, the following error occurs:

[image: Error Message]

I've tried the following ways to solve the problem:

1. Clearing nuget cache
2. Reverting all package versions to 3.1.4
3. Adding the nuget online reference (https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) in package sources.
4. Re-installing Visual Studio
5. Clearing `ComponentModelCache`

Now I'm just wondering if the error is due to using 3.1 framework instead of the latest 5.0.

Comment: What about remove this package: `"Microsoft.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core" Version="3.1.4"`

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately. I believe it is required for the scaffold.

Comment: Hi @Aaron Yong, according to the document, you don't need to install these packages at first. When you add the scaffold, these packages will be automatically included. Maybe you can have a new project to try it.

Comment: Hi @mj1313, I followed your instructions and it worked. I noticed Visual Studio auto downloaded the 3.1.10 version & 3.1.4 version for CodeGeneration.Design. So I went back to my original solution and removed/reinstalled old versions to 3.1.10 which is the latest for netcoreapp3.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aaron Yong I think I found the problem.

```
Include="Microsoft.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.9"
Include="Microsoft.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core" Version="3.1.4"
```

You wrote the wrong name for these two packages. They are

```
Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.9"
Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Core" Version="3.1.4"
```

You add one more `Microsoft` :)

In addition, the version 3.1.9 will be automatically updated to 3.1.10 when add scaffold.

Comment: My bad, that's a typo when I tried to format the question. I've check and it wasn't written like that in my project. Either way, your suggestion to re-download the packages worked. Thanks!

Comment: I've been screwing with this for over an hour now. Nothing works. Why is there no documentation on this? Why do the default templates not work?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing I found on the internet worked to resolve this.
What I did was copy the package references from a working project (all versions are completely mismatched) and it worked.  Microsoft's default templates for Razor page scaffolding no longer work.  Not sure if they just stopped supporting them forever, or if it's just a bug. Who knows.